# regex for interest rate in decimal

Tags: regex, mule

I tried generating a regex for interest rate i.e. `^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?` . but this regex is accepting infinite numbers after the decimal.
I want my regex to accept numbers between 1 to 100 with only two decimal places.
`1.00` to `100.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match either the whole number or exactly 2 decimal places:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|100(?:\.00)?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzWWJ2/1)

If the 2 decimals are mandatory, you can omit the optional non capturing groups:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]?\.[0-9]{2}|100\.00)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[1-9][0-9]?` Match a digit 1-9 and optionally a digit 0-9 to match a range 1-99
  - `\.[0-9]{2}` Match a dot and 2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `100\.00` Match 100.00
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJL4gD/1)

Comment: First approach works  for me . Thanks for the detailed explaination.

Comment: What if I want to match 1.00 to 1000000000.00 ??

Comment: ^[0-9]\d*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|100(?:\.00)\$  will this work ?

Comment: @HMT Do you mean like this? `^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,8}(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|1000000000(?:\.00)?)$` https://regex101.com/r/X1gMgd/1

Comment: ^(?:[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?\.[0-9]{2}|100\.00)$ yes, I created this. 9 digits before decimal and 2 optional decimal